# Importing ics file to an Outlook.AppointmentItem

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2007, icalendar, appointment

I have an Outlook 2007 add-in that is trying to import ics files into Outlook.AppointmentItem objects so that I can read attributes about certain appointments. Currently I am not able to read the ics back into memory. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong.

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
var item = app.Session.OpenSharedItem("C:\\meeting.ics") as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
string meetingBody = item.Body; //<--*my item is null*
```

Thanks

Comment: Does the ICS file have unix or windows end-of-line characters ? I had a problem when I was trying to do something similar - since the ics file when I was trying to import was produced by PHP on a unix platform - changing the end-of-line characters to Windows seemed to help.

Comment: @alshapton... ICS-compatible files REQUIRE line-endings of CRLF -- see RFC 5545, sec 3.1: "The content information associated with an iCalendar object is formatted using a syntax similar to that defined by [RFC2425]. That is, the content information consists of CRLF-separated content lines."

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is due to the fact that [AppointmentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219954.aspx) and [MeetingItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219939.aspx) are different classes so you cannot convert one to another directly. Could you try the following and check if it works?

```
var item = app.Session.OpenSharedItem(@"C:\meeting.ics") as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be because that this ics file just presents a meeting item rather an appointment item. As far as I know, you could try to use code as below,

```
Outlook.MeetingItem item = app.Session.OpenSharedItem(@"C:\SomeMeeting.ics") as Outlook.MeetingItem;
```

If you have any concern for this, please feel free to follow up.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/vsto/thread/f98bfa75-a995-403e-a3fc-5be3a37511d7

Answer (score 1):

Just check its type

```
            Set attObj = ns.OpenSharedItem(strFilename)                

            Select Case TypeName(attObj)
                Case "MeetingItem"
                    Dim miNewMeetingItem As Outlook.MeetingItem
                    Set miNewMeetingItem = attObj
                    ...
                Case "AppointmentItem"
                    Dim miNewAppointmentItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
                    Set miNewAppointmentItem = attObj
                    ...
                Case Else
                    Dim miNew As Outlook.MailItem
                    Set miNew = attObj
                    ...
            End Select

            Set attObj = Nothing
```